# Regex for number optionally followed by comma or hyphen

Tags: regex

I've searched quite a bit on the site but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for.  I have the start of what I need but I can't figure out the last part.  This is what I have so far.

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)+(-[0-9]+)*
```

For my use it's accepting network ports separated by commas and port ranges separated by hyphens.

```
80,443,10001-10003
```

This works fine, but I cannot get it to only accept a single number, such as 80 all by itself.

I've tried variations of the following with no luck:

```
[0-9]|([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)+(-[0-9]+)*)
[0-9] OR ([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)+(-[0-9]+)*)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: if I understood it.    \d+([,-]?\d+)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for exactly 3 terms (as your example):

```
^\d+(,\d+(\d+-\d+)?)?$
```

or for any number of terms where the first must be a non-range, eg `999,123-456,12,13,20-30`:

```
^\d+(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$
```

or for any number of any type, eg `123-456,20-30,88,99,100-102`:

```
^(\d+(-\d+)?(,|$))+$
```

Comment: Awesome.  ^(\d+(-\d+)?(,|$))+$ worked great.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, [it does match 100-110,100](http://rubular.com/r/2j6jMRfeBM).

Comment: Yes, it will, though my regex is more efficient

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew efficiency isn't as much of a concern as readability, especially when it comes to regex, which is hard enough to read already. Making groups non-capturing also adds clutter. Unless you're executing something 100's of times per second, a short regex that is readable is fine. There's such a thing as programmer efficiency too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[0-9]+(?:[-,][0-9]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT1kT0/1)

If you want to ensure a full string match, add `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string anchors):

```
^[0-9]+(?:[-,][0-9]+)*$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT1kT0/2)

The main points:

- `[,-]` - a character class matching `,` or `-`
- `(?:[-,][0-9]+)*` - the `*` quantifier matches *zero or more* characters while `+` matches *one or more* symbols. So, this construct matches *zero or more* sequences of `,` or `-` followed with 1 or more digits.

**If strings like `80-2-2-2-2` should not be matched**, use

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/gY4sO1/1)

Comment: Your regex allows `99-1-1-1-1-1`

Comment: [You are wrong](https://regex101.com/r/yT1kT0/3), and BTW, `99-1-1-1-1-1` should be matched.

Comment: @Bohemian: Because of the `[0-9]+` in the parenthesis, it won't match `99,,,,,,,,,,`.

Comment: I also feel these strings are "pre-filtered", there just should be no "99-1-1-1...".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah OK not `99-----`. And I accept it's probably safe to say that you are just not going to get `1-1-1-1`

Comment: @Bohemian: You have not provided any demo of your regexps. Try. They all match `80-1-1-1-1-1` [in](https://regex101.com/r/oJ2lI9/1) [some](https://regex101.com/r/oJ2lI9/2) [ways](https://regex101.com/r/oJ2lI9/3).

Comment: I don't feel it necessary to add demos. But `^` and `$` added then.